use a mapper inside another mapper interface : mapstruct
Souce DTO :
AuditClass{
  protected ZonedDateTime creationDateTime;
  protected ZonedDateTime lastUpdateDateTime;
}

LocationRequest extends AuditClass{
 //some fields
}

Target DTO :
CachedLocation{
//some fields
protected LocalDateTime updateTime;
}

Mapper to map source to target :
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {LocalAndZonedDateTimeMapper.class})
public interface LocationRequestResponseMapper{

  @Mapping(source = ".", target = "updateTime", qualifiedByName = "getUpdateTime")
  CachedLocation toCachedLocation(LocationRequest location);

  //QUESTION 2: i want to take this method to another mapper so that I can use it across all my request mappings. it there a way i can do it ?
  @Named("getUpdateTime")
  default LocalDateTime getUpdateTime(AuditClass request) {

    //QUESTION 1 : i want to use localAndZonedDateTimeMapper in my method .how can i use another  mapper inside my mapper.  my mapper is an interface an i cannot use abstract class
    if (request.getCreationDateTime() != null) {
      return localAndZonedDateTimeMapper.toLocalDateTime(request.getCreationDateTime());
    } else if (request.getLastUpdateDateTime() != null) {
      return localAndZonedDateTimeMapper.toLocalDateTime(request.getLastUpdateDateTime());

    }
    return null;
  }
}

I have added some challenges to the code itself. Appreciate any help and pointers to solve this issue.
I cannot move getUpdateTime mapping method to localAndZonedDateTimeMapper as i would not be able to use AuditClass in this mapper due to some maven circular dependencies issues
